# Linux + docker container folder that mounted to OS volume + how to know the real limited size

Tags: redhat, docker, containers, disk-volume, kafka

inside the `docker-compose.yml` we configured the following volume

```
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
volumes:
  - /grid/kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

.

```
docker-compose ps
               Name                           Command            State                     Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kafka-node_kafka_1            /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
```

from my understanding -  kafka docker container path - `/var/lib/kafka/data` is mounted to `/var/kafka-data` , when ( `/var/kafka-data` , is the path of the linux OS )

About - `/var/kafka-data` this mount point folder is mounted to OS disk -  `/dev/sdb` while disk `sdb` size is -  `1.8T byte`

So lets summary:

`/var/lib/kafka/data` is kafka docker partition and `/var` is only `100G`

`/var/kafka-data` is the partition that mounted to sdb disk ( on linux OS )

**I want to ask this question to be on the safe side**

Lets say on kafka docker partition - `/var/lib/kafka/data` , size of `/var/../data` is more then `100G`

Is its mean that container partition `/var/lib/kafka/data` is limited to `100G` ??

---

Or `/var` on kafka docker container limited To the external volume that is `1.8T byte`?

**From kafka container side we have  :**

```
# df -h /var
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         101G  7.5G   94G   8% /


df -h  /var/lib/kafka/data/
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/os-rhel_root   101G  7.5G   94G   8% /var/lib/kafka/data
```

**While outside from the container - on the real Linux OS we have**

```
df -h

Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/os-rhel_root  50G  5.3G   45G   11% /
devtmpfs                  12G     0  12G    0% /dev
tmpfs                     12G   156K  12G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb                  1.8T   77M  1.8T   1% /grid/kafka-data
/dev/sda1                 492M  158M  335M  32% /boot
/dev/mapper/os-rhel_var   106G   11G   96G  10% /var
tmpfs                      26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1005
tmpfs                      26G   20K   26G   1% /run/user/0
overlay                   101G  7.5G   94G   8% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8411835673dfedd5986093eb771582dac7317d99f431b832f3baea8ea1aa3e4d/merged
shm                        64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/629aefd21b6042ebfbf1a0a08a882b2f1865137edfb4b2b02f5c9a1681d895e4/mounts/shm
overlay                   101G  7.5G   94G   8% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b4677bed14050337580958bc903bbb733d9464ca8bfc46124c3c506dc064867d/merged
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `docker inspect kafka-node_kafka_1`?

Comment: I did it but I get - []
Error: No such object: kafka-node_kafka_1

Comment: :( OK. You may need to change the name behind `inspect` to the actual container name as reported by `docker ps`.

Comment: sorry its my fault the name is diff - the right name is - afka-single-node_kafka_1 , and I get huge json file

Comment: from the json file - what you want to search?

Comment: It would be interesting to have the wohle thing, but the relevant part is certaionly the volume mappings. Copy the `Mounts` and `Binds` entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100754/discussion-between-shalom-and-linux-fan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps to resolve this question were as follows (discussed in chat):

1. Checking the output of `docker inspect` for the container in question.
   It produces a lot of output, the key parts to consider are the `Binds` and
   `Mounts` sections.
2. Having seen the mounts in place, to avoid having mismatching mounts hiding
   the actual data destionations, we do a check to see that files that are
   created in the container are visible on the host.
   A simple command inside the container like
   `date > /var/lib/kafka/data/test.txt` suffices for
   the purpose and becomes visible under `/grid/kafka-data` on the host.
3. As there is a little chance that somehow docker mounted something above
   the existing volume mount on the host (I have never seen that, but when it's
   important one might better check twice), we create a test file of 400 MiB
   in the container as follows:
   `dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/kafka/data/test.bin count=400 bs=1M`
4. Checking the `df` output on the host shows an increase of the used size of
   ~400 MiB for the volume the data went to. As this is displayed for the
   "correct" mountpoint (with 1.8T size), we are sure that the actual
   limit for writing files is the 1.8T.
5. Afterwards, the test files `test.bin` and `test.txt` are deleted to avoid
   cluttering the system with unnecessary files and space usage.